# react app is successfully created, but npm start throws an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I installed the latest nodejs 19.2.0 on my windows 11 OS rather than the recommended for most users 18.12.1
`npx create-react-app my-first-app` works just fine, it creates all the files and folders without any errors, shows happy hacking message as well, recommends to use `npm start` command. I go inside `my-first-app` folder, go `npm start` and I get a module not found error...like this picture
[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1tci.png)

In youtube tutorials, there is no any error in their pc. `npm start` runs just as easily as `npx create-react-app <anyappname>`.

Comment: Nothing, still the same error...even after restarting my pc, let alone VS Code, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`F:\Tutorial & Practice\Frontend development\React Projects\my-first-app`. With this path to your project, I can see there is an `&` symbol in the `Tutorial & Practice` directory. Sometimes that might cause error. Try renaming the directory without any symbols or even spaces, just to be sure. Then run `npm start`. And if that still doesn't work delete the node_modules folder and then `npm install` again and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

```
npm install react-scripts
```

If the error wasn't solved, then try this:

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm cache clean -f`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm install react-scripts`